# Hibernate - unique constraint violation on update

Tags: java, hibernate, unique-constraint

Consider the situation: I have table with two columns `ID` and `PRIORITY`.
The `PRIORITY` column has unique constrain. 
Example data for the table is:

```
| ID     | PRIORITY |
| -------| ---------|
| 1001   | 1        |
| 1002   | 2        |
| 1003   | 3        |
```

Application have functionality to change the `PRIORITY` of the entries. Let's say i would like to replace the priority of `1003` and `1002`. Do to so i'm trying to update two entities with new `PRIORITY` values: 1) `ID: 1002, PRIORITY: 3` 2) `ID: 1003, PRIORITY: 2`.

I'm doing it in loop one by one with the Hibernate's session method: `session.saveOrUpdate(object);` (`org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.5`)

But obviously it returns constraint violation error, on first update attempt.

How to manage such situations? Is there any kind of 'bulk update' available for such?

**EDIT:**
Here's example code illustrating the case:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class ExampleTable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private Integer priority;

  public ExampleTable(Long id, Integer priority)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.priority = priority;
  }

  public ExampleTable()
  {
  }
  // getters & setters
}
```

```
import org.example.domain.*;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExampleTable et1 = new ExampleTable(1002L, 3);
    ExampleTable et2 = new ExampleTable(1003L, 2);
    List<ExampleTable> list = Arrays.asList(et1, et2);

    Session session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    for (ExampleTable et : list)
    {
      session.saveOrUpdate(et);
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
  }
}
```

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project hibernate-unique-constraint: An exception occurred while executing the Java class. could not execute statement [Duplicate entry '3' for key 'ExampleTable.ExampleTable_pk'] [update ExampleTable set priority=? where id=?]`

Comment: We need to see the full Hibernate Java code please.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general problem than just Hibernate. If you want to update those unique values, you will first need to change them to something different (any kind of temp value will do), and then run your update.

Naturally, even the temp values will need to be unique. You will need to develop a scheme to ensure the constraint is not violated, while still updating to a legal temp value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm wondering if there is other, more general solution for such problem. That maybe Hibernate got something to offer for such.

Comment: All I can say is: good luck. The requirement to have a unique, but changeable, non-primary-key value is what is tricky here. I would be interested if there is a general solution, but expect it will probably some pie-in-the-sky math theory kind of thing. The swap-with-a-temp-value process is all most of us can do at the moment.